# Cloud Backed GeoTIFF Version Problem in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have an ImageCollection of cloud backed GeoTiffs created following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/Earth_Engine_asset_from_cloud_geotiff). Unfortunately, the original COG files had [empty pyramid overviews](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186412979?pli=1) and I needed to update the files with a fixed version. When I overwrote the original files in my cloud bucket with the fixed files, I unwittingly caused a "Failed to load the GeoTIFF at gs://my-bucket/my-object#123456" error, as my bucket is not set up for versioning (see the 'Generations' section of the tutorial linked above). In retrospect, it appears that I should have deleted the asset first, then uploaded the fixed files to my bucket, but I didn't do that. So I now have an ImageCollection that points to old versions of files that no longer exist. Obviously I can no longer load the asset, but I also haven't been able to delete it. While the tutorial is very clear about why I am running into this issue, I have no idea how to fix it.

How can I **either repair my ImageCollection** so that it points to the correct version of the cloud backed GeoTIFFs **or delete it** (so that I can recreate it)?

I am not aware of any way to update the file versions that the ImageCollection is pointing to, but this would be my ideal solution.

I have tried deleting the ImageCollection multiple ways (delete button in the code editor, `earthengine rm {Image_within_ImageCollection}`: both with and without the version number included, `earthengine rm -r {ImageCollection}`), but all give me some version of the same error and do not remove anything. It is clear from the error messages that the commands are trying to remove an old version of the file that no longer exists.

Edit: Possibly related to this [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/249001680)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2023-04-05, I am able to delete the Images individually, but it still does not work to delete the images recursively. Previously, I may have been trying to provide the path to the image as a gsutil path (gs://my-project/etc) or the behavior may have changed since I posted my question. I'm not certain. In any case, this works:

```
earthengine rm projects/{my-project}/assets/{my-ImageCollection}/{my-Image}
```

And even better, a bash for loop allowed this to be automated over the entire ImageCollection:

```
file_list="$(earthengine ls projects/{my-project}/assets/{my-ImageCollection})"  
for f in ${file_list}; do earthengine rm $f; done
```

This removes the Images from the asset in GEE, but leaves the empty ImageCollection and any new versions of the files in GCS.